# If $X$ has density $f(x)=e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}$. Determine the distribution of $Y=\vert X\vert$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> If $X$ has density $f(x)=e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}$ , $-\infty<x<\infty$. Determine the distribution of $Y=\vert X\vert$.

My approach: Note that, $$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(\vert X\vert\leq y)=P(-y\leq X\leq y)$$
$$=P(X\leq y)-P(X\leq -y)=\int_{-\infty}^{y}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx}-\int_{-\infty}^{-y}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx}$$

How continuous this?? any help pls!

Comment: How about $\displaystyle =\int_{-y}^{y}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx} = 2 \int_{0}^{y}{e^{-\frac{ x}{2}}dx}$ as the next steps?

Comment: You must be missing a factor $\frac14$ in the definition of $f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is a probability density function, it must integrate to $1$.

Comment: For self reference/check, you can note that (after multiplying your function by a factor of $1/4$) your $X$ has a Laplace distribution with $(\mu = 0,b=2)$. Hence, it is a "known" result that $Y=|X|$ is exponential r.v. with $1/b = 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Y\ge 0$, so $P(Y\le y)=0$ for $y\le 0$. Thus, we can suppose $y>0$.

Then

$\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{y}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx}-\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{-y}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx}
&=&\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{0}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx}+\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{y}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx}-\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{-y}{e^{-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}}dx}\\
&=&\dfrac{1}{4}\left(2+\int_{0}^{y}{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx}-\int_{-\infty}^{-y}{e^{\frac{ x}{2}}dx}\right)\\
&=&\dfrac{1}{4}\left(2+(2-2e^{-y/2})-2e^{-y/2}\right)\\
&=&1-e^{-y/2}
\end{eqnarray}$\

Comment: For $y\rightarrow\infty$ this converges to $4$, instead of $1$. Also check my comment under the question.

Comment: Done @Matt L. Thanks